# powermock @PrepareForTest is not working with wildcard value

Tags: junit, annotations, powermock

**Version:** powermock-core 1.4.12

**Question:**
According to the [API doc](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.4.12/apidocs/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html), @PrepareForTest should be able to take wildcard like:

@PrepareForTest("com.smin.*")

But in my case, it's just simply doesn't compile, compile error:

*`Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Class<?>[]`*

I had a look at the source code of PrepareForTest, I just don't see how this annotation can take wildcard as its value. Any ideas?

```
@Target( { ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
public @interface PrepareForTest {
    Class<?>[] value() default IndicateReloadClass.class;

    String[] fullyQualifiedNames() default "";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah - the docs don't seem to jibe with reality.  Try:

```
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames={"com.smin.*"})
```

I *think* the resolution of the wildcarded names would happen in the `MockClassLoader` or it's superclass, `DeferSupportingClassLoader`, if you feel like digging deeper.